# Setter changes value of the field only in scope of the setter

Tags: java, hibernate

I have an application which receives messages.  In the message there are fields which can be editable.  When the field is changed it should be saved to the database. Unfortunately, the setter changes the value of given field only in the scope of the setter. Any idea why that happens?  This is the getter and setter code:

```
public String getSenderCharges() {
    Tag tag = swiftMessage.getBlock4().getTagByName("71F");
    String value = tag.getValue();
    Field71F field = new Field71F(value);           
    String senderCharges = field.getValue();
    return senderCharges; 
}

public void setSenderCharges(String senderCharges) {
    Tag tag = swiftMessage.getBlock4().getTagByName("71F");
    String value = tag.getValue();
    if(value.equals(senderCharges)){
        tag.setValue(value);
    }else{
        tag.setValue(senderCharges);
    }
}
```

Comment: framework used to parse Swift messages to XML format

Comment: @JigarJoshi http://www.prowidesoftware.com/en/wife-documentation.html

Answer (score 1):

You are `creating a new object of Tag in setter method` so when you update Tag value in method like `tag.setValu`e is does not reflect outside the setter method.

Tag is local to setter method and it doesn't have scope outside the setter method.

Try this way -

```
public void setSenderCharges(String senderCharges) {
    String value = swiftMessage.getBlock4().getTagByName("71F").getValue();
    if(!value.equals(senderCharges)){
       swiftMessage.getBlock4().getTagByName("71F").setValue(senderCharges);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see any `new Tag` in there. How do you know he's creating it?

Comment: swiftMessage.getBlock4().getTagByName("71F") is returning Tag object thats why Tag tag = swiftMessage.getBlock4().getTagByName("71F"); is not giving anf compile time error

Comment: then do it in this way - swiftMessage.getBlock4().getTagByName("71F").setValue(senderCharges);

Comment: @Paweł [The Javadoc](http://www.prowidesoftware.com/javadoc/com/prowidesoftware/swift/model/SwiftTagListBlock.html#getTagByName(java.lang.String)) disagrees with you.

Answer (score 0):

One thing I notice is a redundant `tag.setValue(value)`. Why set the value that you just got from it? Your whole set-method is equivalent to `swiftMessage.getBlock4().getTagByName("71F").setValue(senderCharges)`.

Why you are not observing this change from other code is not at all obvious from the code you have posted so far. Maybe a concurrency issue?

Comment: I've tried that, and just like before changes value inside setter but once is outside of the scope value doesn't change

Comment: Your issue won't be solved by looking at that line of code, that's the point of my answer. The rest is just a side note.